# How to Enumerate SQL Server Instances

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, enumeration

I´d like to have my application return instances of SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer/Express.

I´m using:

```
System.Data.DataTable lokalni_servery = Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers();

foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in lokalni_servery.Rows)
{
    local_servers.Items.Add(row["Server"].ToString());
}
```

On my friend´s notebook with SQL Server 2008 R2 express 32 bit, it doesn´t find anything, but on my notebook with SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer 64 bit, it finds it almost everytime. 
I need to be able to find this instance of SQL on both machines.

Does anybody know why the application is behaving like this?

Is there a way to alter the method allowing for both notebooks to find the instance?

Comment: useful question +1 - i can't tell you hom many times in the past i scratched my head on this before learning about the browser service

Comment: Related questions: [EnumAvailableSqlServers returns empty list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460567/enumavailablesqlservers-returns-empty-list) or maybe [SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources() does not locate local SQL server 2008 instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824188/sqldatasourceenumerator-instance-getdatasources-does-not-locate-local-sql-serv) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers` enumerates available instances, which means that the servers must be running. Just the fact that they are installed is not enough.

Also the `SQL Server Browser Service` must be running!

See [How to: Start and Stop the SQL Server Browser Service (SQL Server Express)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165734%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) on MSDN

Comment: The servers also have to have TCP/IP enabled, and an exception in the firewall(s) to be found.